# How to include border-radius.htc in MVC architecture to make border-radius work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am using cakephp and want to do `css border-radius` for rounded corners in certain sections. It is working well for all other browser except IE. I am now referring the link http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser for rounded corner support in IE. But the problem is how and where to exactly place the `border-radius.htc`. The pages are loaded from server dynamically and from different folders. So how will i be able to define the relative path as referred to in the given link.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Don't use the `border-radius.htc` in the question. There is a *much* better alternative called [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com). It works the same way, so you'll have the same question, but it's a much better script; more features, and more support.

Comment: ok i will check for that also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I recommend using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) instead of border-radius.htc.

But they both work the same way, so the same question applies to them both.

The answer is to use an absolute URL for the .htc file, rather than a relative one.

This way, as long as you know where your htc file is, you can always refer to it by the same path, and it will always work.

Using relative URLs with htc files does seem to be a recipe for confusion (there's another question here on exactly the same topic right now), but switch to an absolute path and it should just work.

So instead of using

```
behavior:url(../../css/pie.htc);
```

...just use

```
behavior:url(/css/pie.htc);
```

[EDIT]

If that doesn't work, there are still a number of other things which might cause a HTC file not to work.

The most common one is the content type issue. IE is very fussy with this: a HTC file must be served as `text/x-component`. If it isn't, then IE will download it, but then completely ignore it.

If this is the case, you can correct it by adding the content type to your server config. The [CSS3Pie website](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#content-type) has instructions on how to do this. (and also see the same page for other known issues with CSS3Pie, most of which will also apply to `border-radius.htc`)

Comment: This method i have tried for border-radius and in the css file when i define it within a class i dont see any result in IE. What mistake am i doing.

Comment: @user850234 - added another possible solution. hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i used pie, and i was having a heck of a time getting it to work.

Firstly: If you have access to your .htaccess file, add this at the bottom.

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

Next take your .htc file ( or in my case several pie files)
Then when referencing my .htc file:

```
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

if you are unable to add to .htaccess, use the pie.php file that comes with cssPie and reference that instead.

```
behavior: url(/PIE.php);
```

Also make sure your element is relative, with some sort of z-index set:

```
z-index:1;
position:relative;
```

It didn't work in ie8 untill i had that set.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I also use CSS3Pie with CakePHP - I simply place PIE.htc and PIE.php in app/webroot/css, and in my style.css file reference it like so:

```
border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
behavior: url(/css/PIE.php);
```

Comment: The problem i am facing is when a link like /auctions/closed comes. At that point the CSS3Pie url seems to miss the path. Otherwise i am getting the result.

Comment: Hmm.. try using the [mod_rewrite RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) (assuming you are using Apache) to track down where and why the request gets mangled.